# How can MultipleChoiceField be used with or querys in django?

Tags: python, django

When using MultopleChoiceField in django how can a query for all items selected be created? By using:

```
return_queryset = model_name.objects.filter(Q(Column_name=request.POST.getlist('Column_name')[0])|Q(Column_name=request.POST.getlist('Column_name')[1])
```

It will return the or statement but only if you have the correct number of items selected. Is there a shortcut that will allow any number of items to be selected?

You can stack querysets on top of one another, but is there a way to stack or querysets as well? Thanks.

[Or query](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects)

[Queryset](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/request-response/#id3)

[Filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/db/queries/#retrieving-specific-objects-with-filters)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your specific question about stacking `or` clauses - in the general case you can combine Q objects using the functional label for `|` in the built-in `operator` module.

```
import operator
return_queryset = model_name.objects(filter(reduce(operator.or_,
    (Q(Column_name=name) for name in request.POST.getlist('Column_name')))))
```

But for this specific case I would use `in`:

```
return_queryset = model_name.objects.filter(Column_name__in=request.POST.getlist('Column_name'))
```